# Get back my change

Tags: change, ledger-hardware-wallet

Please help. I was new to thew blockchain and did not know about getting change back. when the address to give me my change showed up on my Ledger nano wallet I hit the x instead of the check mark. I don't think I got my change. Can I go up to the same transaction on the blockchain and try again. I noticed there is a  button to receive payment would that work. Does it see that it is my wallet and send the address again.

Comment: Is your balance now lower than expected? It may be helpful if you post the tx id or address in question.

Answer (score 2):

> when the address to give me my change showed up on my Ledger nano wallet I hit the x instead of the check mark. I don't think I got my change

That is not how a transaction works, if you did indeed send a transaction, the change would be returned to you automatically. There would be no additional steps required for you to ‘claim your change’, that simply isn’t how things work.

> Can I go up to the same transaction on the blockchain and try again.

No, if the transaction is already sent, you cannot now ‘resend it’ or ‘try again’.

> noticed there is a button to receive payment would that work. Does it see that it is my wallet and send the address again.

You would use that button for someone else to send you a payment, it has nothing to do with change.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the ledger live app or the ledger chrome app?
when you login, is the balance lower than expected? if you so, i'd advice you try resetting the cashe on both apps.

If you pressed x to cancel, you could simply just reset the ledger with the 24 seed phrase and everything should be fine.